# How can I ctrl click to jump to css file in VS code?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

In VS code when I import *CSS* like this, I cannot *ctrl* click to jump to the file.

```
import './index.scss';
```

but like this can jump,

```
import { BASE_PATH } from '../../../common/constant';
```

Comment: did you ever solve this issue?